# Fundamental matrix of discrete-time Markov chain

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

I have the matrix $$P=\begin{bmatrix}
1-p & p \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$ and I need to compute the fundamental matrix $F$. I can't use the formula $F=(I-P)^{-1}$ because the matrix $I-P$ isn't invertible in this case. According to my textbook, the answer is the 1x1 matrix $(1-(1-p))^{-1}=\frac{1}{p}$ but I don't understand how that can be. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to set absorbing states aside. Here state $2$ is absorbing. That only leaves the $1\times1$ matrix $P'=[1-p]$ for the transition probabilities among the *non*-absorbing states.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about that.